# I want to be able to access data from ci.median

Tags: r

Example data:

```
pq<-c(2.10,  2.35 , 2.35,  3.10 , 3.10  ,3.15 , 3.90,  3.90  ,4.00  ,4.80,  
      5.00 , 5.00,  5.15 , 5.35,  5.50  ,6.00,  6.00 , 6.25 , 6.45)
library(asbio)
test=ci.median(pq,0.957)

test  
95.7% Confidence interval for population median   
Estimate    2.15%   97.85%   
     4.8      3.1      5.5
```

i want something like this

```
test=c(4.8,3.1,5.5 )
```

or a dataframe

```
dataframe =  
Estimate    2.15%   97.85%   
     4.8      3.1      5.5
```

where i can do `table[[2]][1]` gives *3.1* or `table[[2]]` gives the column:

```
2.15%  
3.1
```

Comment: Just a hint:  You can view the whole object with `c(test)`, and `str(test)` will tell you it's a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain a vector with the three values you can try

```
unname(test$ci)
#[1] 4.8 3.1 5.5
```

or

```
setNames(test$ci,test$ends)
#Estimate    2.15%   97.85% 
#     4.8      3.1      5.5
```

Similarly, a data.frame can be defined like this:

```
df1 <- setNames(data.frame(t(test$ci)), test$ends)
#> df1
#  Estimate 2.15% 97.85%
#1      4.8   3.1    5.5
```

From this data.frame, individual columns can be selected as usual.

```
#> df1[2]
#  2.15%
#1   3.1
```